# ¿Es posible utilizar dos sistemas de autenticación en un proyecto de laravel?

Tags: laravel

tengo una duda. ¿Se puede realizar dos sistemas de autenticacion, es decir, dos make:auth? Debo realizar lo siguiente:

- Se tiene un usuario cliente que se loguea en la url ..pagina/login, para ello se utliza una tabla cliente.
- Se tiene otra tabla con diferentes tipos de administradores que deben loguearse en ...pagina/admin/login.

Ya tengo creada la primera parte pero la segunda no se como implementarla o si es posible.

Espero que puedan sugerirme una forma en la cual podría hacerlo.

**Código implementado**

Lo que configure en Auth.php fue los guards y el provider:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

Y en providers

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'pf_cliente'
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Administrator::class,
        'table' => 'pf_usuario',
    ],
],
```

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos llamada pf_usuarios, no utilizo migraciones ya que ya estaba definida, este es el modelo que le asigne:

```
class Admin extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'pf_usuario';
}
```

Este es el controlador que realice en donde reutilizo el trait AuthenticatesUsers:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdministratorController extends Controller
{
   use AuthenticatesUsers;

   public function showLoginForm()
   {
      return view('admin.login');
   } 

   public function username()
   {
      return 'emailpf';
   }
```

}

Mi duda es si debo de configurar esta parte del trait en el controlador porque agregue otro guard

```
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
```

Comment: Si es posible, pero tienes que configurarlo, en `config/auth.php`, hay comentarios sobre como configurar otro servicio de autenticacion, de base laravel tiene el "web" y el "api".

Comment: Es lo mismo si usas Roles en Laravel, que un admin acceda a todas las paguinas y un cliente a ciertas paguinas

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido, he estado intentando hacerlo de esa manera configurando otro guard "admin" a parte del de web y api, asi como otro provider, ademas en mi controlador estoy intentando utilizar el trait AuthenticatesUsers, sin embargo aqui se manda a llamar en un metodo que trae el guard a utilizar, ¿como se que si se esta llamando al guard admin que creé y no al que esta como default o como puedo cambiarlo? si se muestra dentro del metodo como Auth::guard()

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que quieres decir, podrias enseñarnos lo que has ido haciendo? El modelo, la config del auth, el controller, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que esta respuesta no solucione tu problema al 100%, pero deberia guiarte un poco por el camino. He añadido modificaciones y comentarios al codigo que nos enseñas para que veas que cambiar:

### Modelo Admin o Administrador:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable { // Veo que en la config llamas al modelo Administrator, pero aqui lo llamas Admin, tienes que corregir el que este mal.

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $table = 'pf_usuario';

}
```

### Configuración del provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'pf_cliente'
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Administrator::class, // El modelo que nos muestras es Admin, tienes que corregir el que este mal.
        'table' => 'pf_usuario',
    ],
],
```

### Ejemplo de como usar el guard admin:

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        // Tu validación
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['{campo_identificativo}' => '{variable_identificativa}', 'password' => '{contraseña}']) {

        // Login correcto
    }
    // Fallo
}
```

Comment: No llevo mucho tiempo en esto de laravel, me podrías explicar para que sirve attempt(), lo he visto en varias partes no entiendo realmente para que se utiliza.

Comment: `attemp()` acepta argumentos el campo de identificación y la contraseña, pudiendo añadir uno extra de "recuerdame". Lo que hace `attemp()`, como dice el nombre, es intentar "loguear" al usuario mediante el guard, en este caso "admin". En caso de que no consiga loguear al usuario devolvera false.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora me queda más claro. Si realice los cambios que me habias comentado, aunque la parte del adminLogin la implemente de diferente forma utilizando la función guard. Solo que ahora tengo un problema al momento de entrar me redirige al login del cliente. ¿Podria publicarlo aqui o en otra pregunta?

Comment: Lo suyo seria a otra pregunta ya que es algo diferente, aun asi, la redirección suele venir de parte del middleware, indicale que redirija a donde tu quieras.